# I want to show employee names of each department on the side. How can I do that in Django?

Tags: python, django

[image]

This is my model; employee and department class. Employee is a child of department.

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
class emplye(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email= models.CharField( max_length=20)
    phone =models.CharField( max_length=20)
    address =models.CharField( max_length=20)
    # dept_id =models.IntegerField(max_length=20)
    depertment =models.ForeignKey("depertment", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class depertment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField( max_length=20)
    about =models.CharField( max_length=20)
```

Here is my views.py file. I am annotating employee objects and from department. I am trying to show the employee names in each department .

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
from django.db.models import Count

def index(request):

    b = department.objects.all().annotate(emp=(Count('emplye')))

    print("Return:",b)
    print()
    print("SQL Query:",b.query)

    context = {
        'b':b,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'employee/index.html',context)
```

Here is my html file

```
#index.html
{% for z in b %}
    <h1>{{ z.name }} {{ z.emp }}  {{z.employee.name}} </h1>
{% endfor %}
```

[image: expecting employee names in the highlighted area]

Comment: You want to display all values in one line?

Comment: i want to show the epmlye names in the same row as they are in. like 

"it 3 emp1 emp2 emp3"
"software 2 emp4 emp5"

Comment: Displaying the values in one line is a front-end thing. It has nothing to do with Django/Python. Use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a custom template filter.

```py
@register.filter
def get_department_employees(department):
    employees = emplye.objects.filter(depertment=department)
    return employees
```

Then in your template you can access these employees using the `with` tag.

```html
{% for z in b %}
    {% with employees=z|get_department_employees %}
         <h1>{{ z.name }} {{ z.emp }}  {% for employee in employees %}{{employee.name}}{% endfor %} </h1>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

To learn how to set up custom template filters read the [**[Django-Docs]** - Custom Template Tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/)

> *Note: Assuming you're using the English language, it may be worth checking the spelling for your models. **depertment --> department** , **emplye --> employee**.*